# Add attribute to property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, attributes, data-annotations

How to do the following?

I have a MVC site where an admin can create questions which other user must answer. With the creation of a question he can add a IsRequired option to it.

I store the questions in a db with columns:

- QuestionText (nvarchar)
- IsRequired (bit)

So when a user goes to a page he can see the questions made by the admin. If it is a required questions he MUST answer it before he can continue.

How can I enforce this with proper model binding? I can get the data and check for each question whether it is required, but how can I add some kind of Require Attribute to this property so that in my webpage the user gets an error message indicating he must fill in this question?

Or what would be the best way to do this?

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) have some useful validation attributes such as `[RequiredIfTrue]` that will suit your needs

Comment: @StephenMuecke very nice one I would like to use it didn't knew about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K Foolproof did the job.

```
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfTrue("IsRequired", ErrorMessage = "Elabe")]
    public string RequiredString { get; set; }
```

This says that when the property IsRequired == true --> the property RequiredString must not be empty and will receive the warning "Elabe".

Thanks Stephen